# Problem using react-hook-form with react select and zod

Tags: reactjs, react-select, zod

Somebody can help me what i doing wrong?

```
const entitySchema = z.object({
    value: z.string(),
    label: z.string(),
  });

  const newTransactionFormValidationSchema = z.object({
    entity_type: entitySchema,
    entity_name: z.string(),
    asset_id: z.number(),
    transaction_type: z.string(),
    amount: z.number().min(1).max(100),
  })

 type NewTransactionFormData = z.infer<typeof newTransactionFormValidationSchema>

  const { control, register, handleSubmit } = useForm<NewTransactionFormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(newTransactionFormValidationSchema),
    }

 const entity_type = [
    { value: 'associado', label: 'Associado' },
    { value: 'fornecedor', label: 'Fornecedor' },
  ]

  const clients = clientsList.map((client) => ({
    value: client.clie_codigo,
    label: client.clie_razaosocial,
  }))

  const asset_type = [
    { value: '1', label: 'Caixa amarela' },
    { value: '2', label: 'Caixa vermelha' },
    { value: '3', label: 'Pallet' },
  ]

  const transaction_type = [
    { value: 'entrada', label: 'Entrada' },
    { value: 'saida', label: 'Saída' },
  ]
  


<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleRegisterNewTransaction)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          {...register('entity_type')}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Select 
              {...field}
              options={entity_type}
              required={true} 
              styles={{ control: (baseStyles) => ({...baseStyles, width: '150px'})}}
              placeholder="Selecione.."
            />
            )}
        />

return (
    <NewTransactionContainer>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleRegisterNewTransaction)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          {...register('entity_type')}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Select 
              {...field}
              options={entity_type}
              required={true} 
              styles={{ control: (baseStyles) => ({...baseStyles, width: '150px'})}}
              placeholder="Selecione.."
            />
            )}
        />

        <Controller 
          control={control}
          {...register('entity_name')}
          render={({ field }) => 
            <Select 
              {...field}
              options={clients} 
              required={true}
              styles={{ control: (baseStyles) => ({...baseStyles, width: '300px'})}}
              placeholder="Selecione uma entidade.."
            />
          }
        />
```

This is giving me error in the Select and options props of the react-select component as follow

**Select error**

```
Type '{ options: { value: string; label: string; }[]; required: true; styles: { control: (baseStyles: CSSObjectWithLabel) => { width: string; accentColor?: AccentColor | string[] | AccentColor[] | undefined; ... 938 more ...; label?: string | undefined; }; }; ... 5 more ...; ref: RefCallBack; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<PublicBaseSelectProps<{ value: string; label: string; }, false, GroupBase<{ value: string; label: string; }>>>'.
  Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.
    Type '(event: { value: string; label: string; } | ChangeEvent<Element>) => void' is not assignable to type '(newValue: SingleValue<{ value: string; label: string; }>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<{ value: string; label: string; }>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'newValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'SingleValue<{ value: string; label: string; }>' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; label: string; } | ChangeEvent<Element>'.
          Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; label: string; } | ChangeEvent<Element>'.ts(2322)
(alias) const Select: StateManagedSelect
import Select
```

**options error**

```
Type '{ value: number; label: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly (string | GroupBase<string>)[]'.
  Type '{ value: number; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | GroupBase<string>'.
    Property 'options' is missing in type '{ value: number; label: string; }' but required in type 'GroupBase<string>'.ts(2322)
types.d.ts(5, 14): 'options' is declared here.
Select.d.ts(184, 5): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<PublicBaseSelectProps<string, false, GroupBase<string>>, StateManagedPropKeys> & Partial<...> & StateManagerAdditionalProps<...> & RefAttributes<...>'
(property) options?: OptionsOrGroups<string, GroupBase<string>> | undefined
Array of options that populate the select menu
```

If I remove the type of `useForm` the errors of the Select and option go away

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Were you able to find a solution for this?